.dateTime.hour(.defaultDigits(amPM: .omitted)) does not work as expected
I want to format only the hour part of a date using Swift 5.9.2. However, while we expect it to remove the leading 0's according to the .defaultDigits option, unfortunately it does not.
var dateComponents = DateComponents()
dateComponents.year = 2024
dateComponents.month = 8
dateComponents.day = 26
dateComponents.hour = 9
dateComponents.minute = 45

let date = Calendar.current.date(from: dateComponents)
print(date!.formatted(.dateTime.hour(.defaultDigits(amPM: .omitted)).locale(Locale(identifier: "de")))) // Prints "09 Uhr" instead of "9 Uhr"
print(date!.formatted(.dateTime.hour(.defaultDigits(amPM: .abbreviated)).locale(Locale(identifier: "de")))) // Prints "09 Uhr" instead of "9 Uhr"
print(date!.formatted(.dateTime.hour(.defaultDigits(amPM: .narrow)).locale(Locale(identifier: "de")))) // Prints "09 Uhr" instead of "9 Uhr"
print(date!.formatted(.dateTime.hour(.defaultDigits(amPM: .wide)).locale(Locale(identifier: "de")))) // Prints "09 Uhr" instead of "9 Uhr"

Formatter should remove leading zeros

I haven't used the Date.formatted() function very much. It doesn't seem to give you control over things like the number of digits used for the hour. I'd suggest using the older DateFormatter instead. That gives you full control over the format of the output:
let hourFormatter = DateFormatter()
hourFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "de")
hourFormatter.dateFormat = "H"
print(hourFormatter.string(from: date))


I would have to suggest that Apple believes that "09 Uhr" is correct for the Germany locale. If you think otherwise, perhaps a bug report would be in order. In any case, if you simply want to remove the leading zero for presentation purposes, just trim leading zeros from the output string and present the result to the user (rather than trying to solve the problem at the format level).
Alternatively, if you just want the number without the leading zeros, but with "Uhr" appended, you can use a verbatim style:
    let date = Calendar.current.date(from: dateComponents)!
    let formatString: Date.FormatString = """
    \(hour: .defaultDigits(clock: .twentyFourHour, hourCycle: .oneBased)) Uhr
    """
    let style = Date.VerbatimFormatStyle(
        format: formatString,
        timeZone: .current, calendar: .current
    )
    let output = date.formatted(style)
    print(output)


Cool. I didn't know about Date.VerbatimFormatStyle. Thanks for that.
